# NoClassDefFoundError: scala/math/Ordering with spring-kafka-test 2.5.7

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-kafka

I have a small library that provides a JUnit 5 extension around `EmbeddedKafkaBroker`, which tries to be more performant than just using `@DirtiesContext` by instead resetting the offsets to latest between tests instead of throwing away the whole context.

My build.gradle is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntime 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

This resolves to using `spring-kafka:2.5.7` and various Scala libraries at `2.12`. When extension tries to start the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker`, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/math/Ordering$$anon$7

    at kafka.api.ApiVersion$.orderingByVersion(ApiVersion.scala:45)
    at kafka.api.ApiVersion.compare(ApiVersion.scala:139)
    at kafka.api.ApiVersion.compare$(ApiVersion.scala:138)
    at kafka.api.KAFKA_2_5_IV0$.compare(ApiVersion.scala:339)
    at kafka.api.KAFKA_2_5_IV0$.compare(ApiVersion.scala:339)
    at scala.math.Ordered.$greater$eq(Ordered.scala:91)
    at scala.math.Ordered.$greater$eq$(Ordered.scala:91)
    at kafka.api.KAFKA_2_5_IV0$.$greater$eq(ApiVersion.scala:339)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1561)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1269)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:313)
```

The searching I've done so far has only turned up issues with overriding particular kafka or scala versions, which I am not doing. Any ideas what I'm missing, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same issue here. I looked into the spring-kafka 2.5.7.RELEASE which is the one used by Spring Boot 2.3.5 and added same scala dependency to my project as a workaround to my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.11")
}
```

This solved my problem for the moment. Hope it will get fixed in next spring-kafka version.

Comment: This is a known problem - it is cause by Boot's prescribed version of Jackson pulling in incompatible scala libraries. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1604 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23979 for more information. Your "workaround" is the correct solution; there is nothing we can do - blame the scala folks for making such a radical changes in a bug fix release.

Comment: The other solution is to upgrade to `spring-kafka` 2.6.3 and `kafka-clients` 2.6.0.  You can do that by upgrading to Boot 2.4.0, or by overriding the dependencies with Boot 2.3.x https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.3',
'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.5.8.RELEASE',
'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.5.8.RELEASE',
'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.5.1',
'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.5.1:test',
'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.11' these dependencies would also work